# Custom Post Type + Category archive

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, categories, loop, permalinks

I have created a WP stack with 3 post types:

```
 1. Post (default)
 2. Event
 3. Place
```

These 3 post types share the same taxonomy, that being the default WP category, here are some example categories:

```
 1. Shopping
 2. Concerts
 3. Sports
```

I need to create a category archive for each of the post types:

```
eg. http://example.com/event/concerts  /* cat = concerts, post_type = event */
eg. http://example.com/post/concerts   /* cat = concerts, post_type = post */
eg. http://examplecom/place/shopping   /* cat = shopping, post_type = place */
```

However, I'm not sure how to go about with this... would creating individual template files like `category-event.php`, `category-place.php` and `category-post.php` work?

In which case, would I have to do a custom WP Query with the relevant `$args` or does the query come from the URL?

I'm not even sure of how to create a link to the page. I've tried `/event/concerts/` and `/event/category/concerts/` - in both scenarios I get a 404 error, not even an empty loop.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Your categories are, shopping , concerts and sports.
So in order to create a category archive, you should follow category-{category-slug}.php 
Hence your file name should be : 
category-shopping.php 
category-sports.php 
category-concerts.php.
And after this try with **/event/category/concerts/** - this will solve your problem.